# Can I cache external scripts locally on my server?

Tags: caching, pagespeed

I am working on improving my Pagespeed score. One problem I am running into is that pagespeed is suggesting me "Leverage Browser Caching" for Google adsense scripts.

These scripts are external. So my question is... Is it even possible to cache external scripts on my server ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the cache lifetime for resources from other domains. However, there may be something you can do: Are you using the asynchronous version of AdSense? That should improve your sure speed. See more information: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en

Comment: Yes I am already using asynchronous version of adsense...
If I cannot cache these scripts, then why is google telling me to do so??
Maybe they need to think about their suggestions...

Comment: Well, you don't need to fix all the suggestions. Your page *is* being slowed down by an external script that has short cache lifetime. You *can* make that better (by not including the external JS). The choice is yours, however I can understand that you want to keep adsense :) I think that the goal of PageSpeed is to tell you what is causing your page to be slow, even if some of that is out of your control.